# TableViewController hierarchy header text

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController` to simplify pushing/popping of views. When a user presses one of the table cells I want to show a different `UITableView` (go a layer deeper). I've set up my storyboard like this:

[image: storyboard]

The "Pet preferences" cell is hooked up to show the new table view I want to show on the right. I'm trying to add header text to the new tableViewController just like how the first tableViewController has "Settings" at the top. However, I'm not able to for some reason. Did I set up my storyboard wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` do this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";
```